# How to implement multilingual labels in tx:mask (TYPO3)?

Tags: typo3, tx-mask

I would like implement multilingual labels in TYPO3 mask. After implementing with the following FLUID-code the label does not change based on the chosen language:

```
<f:link.page pageUid="{data.tx_mask_inhalt_text_link}">
<f:if condition="{TSFE.sys_language_uid} == 1">
    <f:then>
         enter code here`Read more
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
         Weiterlesen
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

</f:link.page>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue with:

MASK-Template:

```
<f:translate key="label" />
```

TYPO3-Setup:

```
plugin.tx_mask._LOCAL_LANG.de.label = Weiterlesen
plugin.tx_mask._LOCAL_LANG.en.label = Read more
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: You can even use this in other templates, too:
<f:translate key="more" extensionName="mask" />

Answer (score 2):

You can use XLIFF files to localize values in TYPO3. This is neither limited to nor different for mask templates (as these are common Fluid templates).

A `locallang.xlf` contains entries like:

```
<trans-unit id="readmore">
    <source>Read more</source>
    <target>weiterlesen</target>
</trans-unit>
```

In the HTML template you can use the `f:translate` viewhelper:

```
<f:translate key="LLL:EXT:your_extension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:readmore" />
```

This will render the value depending on the current frontend language.

---

This is the usual way of translating in TYPO3. Please refer to these official documentations for all details:

- [XLIFF | TYPO3 documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Internationalization/XliffFormat.html)
- [f:translate | Fluid guide](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Translate.html)

Comment: For people going that route I'd like to add that it's `LLL:EXT:your_extension` not `LLL:your_extension`. Also `locallang.xlf` is assumed to be the configured default language's file, other languages would resolve to `de.locallang.xlf` (assuming the current frontend language is `de`) etc...